# if 2 cells blank, then do if statement, if 3rd cell is not blank, then do if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

Multiple criteria if statement, based on blank and non blank cells returning different "true" statement.

If cells K (DATE) and F (dollar amount) are blank, then if cell F=500 then "REQUEST" otherwise ""
I have this portion of the formula working:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(K49), ISBLANK(F49)),"",IF(F49=500,"REQUEST","")))
```

I need to add another if statement based on cell I49 (DATE) and the below works alone, not combined with the above formula.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(I49)),"RCVD","")
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about sheets of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Can you verify?

1. If either K49 or F49 is blank, make the resulting cell empty
2. If F49 = 500, and neither K49 nor F49 is empty, set it to REQUEST, otherwise set it to blank

I don't see how the third criteria fits in.

Could you please expand?